# zsh: command not found: docker exec -it

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-registry

I am getting following error while executing docker command `docker exec -it container_name bash`

```
zsh: command not found: docker exec -it
```

I have tried bash as well, still getting the same error

```
bash: docker exec -it: command not found
```

Can someone please help me with it.

Thanks

Comment: Is docker installed?

Comment: If you're getting that exact message, you probably have some sort of quoting or character-encoding problem; that message suggests the shell is seeing something along the lines of `'docker exec -it' container_name bash` and not splitting out `docker` into its own word.  Do you have extra quotes?  Are the spaces plain ASCII spaces U+0020?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a PATH issue:

```
echo $PATH
which docker
```

If docker is installed, make sure the `$PATH` references its `bin` folder.